# Dgraph query returning data even if the uid is not present

Tags: node.js, dgraph

I was querying dgraph for the user's details, but it's returning an array with one object having the key uid and value as the "uid_string" that I queried for, even if no user exists with that uid.

The query:

```
{
  User(func: uid(0x44)) {
    uid
    name
  }
}
```

The result that I am getting:

```
"User": [
      {
        "uid": "0x44"
      }
    ]
```

The expected result should be:

```
"User": []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uid()` function is like an identity function: it will return to you the uid specified, regardless if it has any incoming or outgoing edges to it.

A uid without any edges is effectively an orphan node, and has no impact to how data is stored or queried in Dgraph.